# sum of all digits of a number in JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, function, integer-arithmetic

I wanted to write a program that calculates the sum of all digits of a number. I saw similar posts but none of them were written in JavaScript inside  HTML. I am not getting any output, the webpage is entirely blank.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id ="demo"></p>
<script>

n=prompt("enter a number");
function adddigits(n)
{
    s=0;
    while(n!=0)
    {
        s=s+n%10;
        n=n/10;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "sum of the digits" + s ;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not calling your function anywhere.

Comment: You’re also not declaring your variables. It’s a good idea to do that.

Answer (score 2):

> program that calculates the sum of all digits of a number

***The right way:***

```js
n = prompt("enter a number");

function getSum(n) {
  if (!/^\d+$/.test(n)) {   // check for non-digit input
   throw new Error('Wrong number: ' + n);
  }
  
  // converting each digit from text representation into number 
  // and getting sum of them
  var sum = n.split('').map(Number).reduce(function(a,b) { return a + b; });
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "sum of the digits: " + sum ;
}

getSum(n);  // calling function to calculate the sum of numbers
```

```html
<p id ="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling your function anyway. You can do that by adding follwing code to your :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var n=prompt("enter a number");
    adddigits(n); 
});
```

Comment: how is it wrong to simply call the function by writing  adddigits(n); ?

Comment: yes you are right you can call your function without writing the document.ready()

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to remove the trailing part of the rest of the division, e.g. `n=n/10` becomes `n=Math.floor(n/10)`.

```js
var n = prompt("enter a number");
adddigits(n);

function adddigits(n) {
  var s = 0;
  while (n != 0) {
    s = s + n % 10;
    n = Math.floor(n / 10);
  }
  alert(s);
}
```

Comment: @fancois-XavierAeberhard how is n=n/10 wrong to write?

Comment: Without the Math.floor call, your method will return 2.1 for 11 (1+1.1).